# Solve $x^n+y^n=2015$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Determine the natural numbers $x,y,n$ matching equality
$$x^n+y^n=2015.$$

I noticed for $n = 1$ the equation has solutions $(x, 2015-x), x$ integer.

For $n = 2$, given that $x$ and $y$ are different parities taking $x = 2k$ and $y=2m + 1$  we come to contradiction.

What must be done to $n\geq3$?

Comment: You could just brute force it, using that $\sqrt[3]{2015} < 13$, $\sqrt[4]{2015} < 7$< and so on.

Comment: @user you may want to explain that in an answer, cause I don't see exactly how to proceed...

Comment: Are you using 2015 because of the year?

Comment: @user How would that help?  Trying to cube root both sides won't even remove $n$ from the left side.

Comment: @SimpleArt See my answer.

Comment: Does it help to notice that $x$ and $y$ are interchangeable?

Comment: I'm already looking forward to next year.

Comment: @hardmath I'm still looking backwards to last year, wondering why I didn't join this site earlier.

Comment: Matching parity????  Why?   If the parity matches the sum is even and there is no solution (not even for n = 1).  If parity doesn't match the solution is not trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piggybacking off user's answer that we need only concern ourselves with a few odd exponents, with $x\lt y$ also pretty small, let's use the fact that $x+y$ divides $x^n+y^n$ for odd $n$ and $x^p\equiv x$ mod $p$ for prime $p$.

Note that $2014$ is not an $n$th power for any $n\gt1$, so we can assume $1\lt x\lt y$.  Note also that  $2015=5\cdot13\cdot31$. Finally, $\sqrt[3]{2015}\lt13$ means we don't have to worry about potential solutions with $x+y\ge25$, which means we need only consider solutions with $x+y=5$ or $x+y=13$.

For $n=3$, we have $x+y\equiv x^3+y^3=2015\equiv2$ mod $3$, so $x+y=5$ is the only possibility, which means $x=2,y=3$ is the only possibility, but $2^3+3^3$ is way smaller than $2015$.

For $n=5$, we have $x+y\equiv x^5+y^5=2015\equiv0$ mod $5$, so again $x+y=5$ is the only possibility, and again $2^5+3^5$ is too small.

For $n=7$, we have $x+y\equiv x^7+y^7=2015\equiv6$ mod $7$, so $x+y=13$ is the only possibility.  But $7^7$ is already way too big.  (Alternatively, note that $\sqrt[7]{2015}\approx2.965\lt3$ already rules out any solutions.)

For $n=9$, working mod $3$, we have $x+y\equiv x^9+y^9\equiv2$ mod $3$, so again $2^9+3^9$ is the only possibility, which is too large.  (Or, again, $\sqrt[9]{2015}\lt3$ rules out any solutions.)

Comment: Oops, sorry, of course.

Answer (score 10):

Any solution with $n$ even can be used to give a solution with exponent $2$. So it suffices to study $n$ odd. Since $\log_2 2015 \approx 10.97 < 11$, we can ignore all exponents larger than $9$. This reduces it to $3, 5, 7, 9$.

- Exponent $9$: $2015 - 2^9 = 1503$ is not a ninth power and  $3^9$ is larger than $2015$, so no solutions.
- Exponent $7$: $2015 - 2^7 = 1887$ is not a seventh power and $3^7$ is larger than $2015$, so no solutions.
- Exponent $5$: Check directly that $x = 2, 3$ or $4$ leads to no solution, and $5^5$ is too large. No solutions.
- Exponent $3$: I'll leave it to you to check there are no solutions. You can check for $x \le 12$.

Comment: Note that this answer is the opposite of clever. I'm sure there's some nice number theory based on the fact that $2015 = 5 \times 13 \times 31$ that can be used here. Probably at least for exponent $5$....

Comment: One cleverness is that because $31$ is a factor and is $3 \pmod 4$, there is no solution for $n=2$ and therefore, as you say, any even $n$.  I think this is a fine approach for the problem at hand.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah, quite nice. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the fact that for odd $n$, $x+y$ divides $x^n+y^n$.  For $n=3$ this pretty much means $x+y=13$ (since $5$ is too small and $31$ or bigger is too big), so it's enough to check $x\le6$.

Comment: @RossMillikan or just that 2015 is 3 mod 4.

Answer (score 3):

Since $2015=5\cdot 13\cdot 31$, and the multiplicities of the primes congruent $3$ modulo $4$ are odd (only $p=31$ to consider here), it follows that $2015$ cannot be represented as the sum $x^2+y^2$, by Fermat's theorem. This does not only work for $2015$. Also, characterisation of two cubes is known, see [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL6/Broughan/broughan25.pdf). Of course, $2015$ is still small enough to check all cases. For bigger numbers however, one would like to apply more number theory.

Edit: In case we would like to have more positive integer solutions to $x^n+y^n=m$, then $m=4097$ is the smallest number (besides $2$) which is a sum of two squares and two positive cubes. Indeed, the equation $x^n+y^n=4097$ has integer solutions for $n=1,2,3,4,6,12$:
$$
4097=1+4096=1^2+64^2=1^3+16^3=1^4+8^4=1^6+4^6=1^{12}+2^{12}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  $n<12$ because $1^{12}+2^{12}>2015$

Comment: ...at this point I would just run a program in Python ;)

Comment: @ForeverMozart isn't that the answer to everything?